# How can I return an Array list value into a separate array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to create a program that gets the dot product of two vectors. I approached it by creating an Array List (named distance). I can make this program run with hardcoded numbers by changing this line in the main method.

```
double vect_A[] = distnace(mag);
double vect_B[] = distance(dista);
```

I know the code above doesn't run, is it possible to return those specific values into separate arrays? Or am I approaching this problem incorrectly. I am very new to Java any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
//java implementation for dot product
// and cross product of two vector.
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class practiceMats {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        vector();
        double vect_A[] = distnace(mag);
        double vect_B[] = distance(dista);

        // dotProduct function call
        System.out.print ( "Dot product:");
        System.out.println (dotProduct(vect_A, vect_B)) ;
    }


    static double n = 3.0;

    // Function that return
    // dot product of two vector array.
    static double dotProduct(double vectorA[], double vectorB[])
    {     
        double product = 0.0;

        // Loop for calculate cot product
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            product = product + vectorA[i] * vectorB[i];
        return product;
    }

    static ArrayList<Integer> vector() 
    {
        ArrayList<Integer>distance= new ArrayList<Integer>();  
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your array length: ");
        int s = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter your distance: ");
            int dista = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            distance.add(dista); 
            System.out.println("Enter your distance: ");
            int mag = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            distance.add(mag); 
        }
        return distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title is missing a verb...

Comment: Oh my apologies ill edit that now, there edited it sorry its been a long day of studying haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this slightly different, rather than trying to read both the array using a single method call, I would call it twice to read the array input from the user. That ways the user will also be aware of the values he has entered for arrayA and arrayB.
Thus your vector method would look like:

```
     static ArrayList<Integer> vector(int vectorSize) 
    {
    System.out.println("Kindly provide details for the Vector: ");
    ArrayList<Integer>distance= new ArrayList<Integer>();  
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter your distance: ");
    int dista = scan.nextInt();
    distance.add(dista); 
    }       
   return distance;
    }
```

The main method would look like:

```
  public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
       System.out.println("Please enter your array length: ");
       int s = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        List<Integer> vectorA= vector(s);
        List<Integer> vectorB= vector(s);
        double vect_A[] = //convert your List vectorA to array
        double vect_B[] = //convert your List vectorB to array

         // dotProduct function call
        System.out.print ( "Dot product:");
        System.out.println (dotProduct(vect_A, vect_B)) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you spell distance correctly after "vect_A".

(Adding as an answer because I can't comment yet...)